# PHP Laravel 5.4.21. Eloquent save insert in first row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with saving Eloquent models. For example:

```
$game = Game::select(['bank', 'state', 'quantity_of_players'])->find($id)->first();
$game->bank += $game->bet;
$game->quantity_of_players++;
$game->save();
```

As far as i know from documentation, `save()` should insert changed values in a row with `$id`, but instead it inserts in a very first row. What's an issue, and how to save it properly to my database in specified row.

Migration for this model:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->enum('state', ['wait', 'search', 'accept', 'play', 'finish']);
        $table->smallInteger('quantity_of_players');
        $table->smallInteger('ready_players');
        $table->smallInteger('finished_players');
        $table->integer('bank');
        $table->smallInteger('bet');
    });
}
```

Would really appreciate any help with this.

P.S. All `SELECT` requests works perfectly such as Eloquent `create()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find()` method internally calls `first()`. It's also a good practise to check if the row exists before proceeding. Using `findOrFail()` does this for you.

```
$game = Game::findOrFail($id);
$game->bank += $game->bet;
$game->quantity_of_players++;
$game->save();
```

**Edit**

If you're insistent on selecting the columns even for the update. Then do this

```
$game = Game::whereId($id)->first(['bank', 'state', 'quantity_of_players']);
```

Comment: Check for existence are made in a wrapper function which calls this code. Is there any way to get only selected columns, not all of them?

Comment: @JonnySmith since all you're doing is update, it doesn't matter. This is preferable to keep the code clean. If you want the selected columns then check my edit on the answer

Comment: Issue still remains. It's still insert in a first. Can it be caused by placing "id" in $guarded?

Comment: What's the content of `$id`? Can you run `dd($game)` after fetching the game model and post the results. The `$guarded` property is not an issue.

Comment: "Id" is an increment. `Game {#154
  +timestamps: false
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "id"
  ]
  #fillable: array:6 [
    0 => "state"
    1 => "quantity_of_players"
    2 => "ready_players"
    3 => "finished_players"
    4 => "bank"
    5 => "bet"
  ]
+exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [
    "id" => 1
    "state" => "wait"
    "quantity_of_players" => 0
    "ready_players" => 0
    "finished_players" => 0
    "bank" => 30
    "bet" => 30
  ]`

Comment: @JonnySmith you're trying to access the `bet` column in `$game->bank += $game->bet;`. Which you're missing from the select. Anyway glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
$game = Game::find($id);
$game->bank += $game->bet;
$game->quantity_of_players++;
$game->save();
```

Comment: And there is no other way to select required columns? Cause it's unlikely to get all columns.

Comment: What i'm guessing is that since you don't select everything, it inserts again since laravel doesn't 100% find the model in the db. (I think)

Comment: There is a wrapper which call function that contain this code, and check for existence of row made in a wrapper. So required row always exist. For example i get the row with id=2, and insert in a row with id=2, but instead of it. It insert in a row with id=1, always.

Comment: You can try using the mass update and thus not having that problem but i don't think that getting every column is indeed a problem 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates